# How do I use forEach to loop through this

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, foreach

```
let arr = [{
question:{
 q1 : 123,
 q2 : 44
}
}];
```

I've tried using forEach loop to do it, but it returns nothing.

Comment: There's only one element in `arr` so why `.forEach()`? `.forEach()` doesn't "return" anything -> [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: post your code so others can point out your mistake

Comment: That's a small part of it, but I've fixed the problem. but you can still say something

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array then you can do either `map` or `forEach`.

```
  arr.forEach()
```

However you have to pay attention to the internal structure of the item as well, ex. in your case

```
  arr.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.question.q1)
  })
```

And if you want the transformation, then

```
  const transformedArr = arr.map(item => item.question.q1)
```